# Help with passing an object back to post action please

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a get method passing in an object of type Store to the view, upon creating the view using the menu dialog (i.e. Create a strongly-typed view) it properly scaffolds out the form when I choose the view content to be Edit.  Without changing anything on the view I add a post method that accepts a store object as the parameter.  The properties on the object are never populated with the form data and I am unable to figure out why.  A Request.Form.Count shows 14 items which is correct minus the Id which would make 15.  If I type out each parameter separately they do get set.  I can also use the FormCollection to get the values, but sure would be nice to pass the entire object back in and use that.

Is there a reason why this might be happening?

Store Definition:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace DomainModel
{
    public class Store : GuidIdentityPersistenceBase
    {
        private string _address1;

        private string _address2;

        private string _city;

        private string _county;

        private int _oldStoreNumber;

        private string _faxNumber;

        private bool _hasHydraulicHose;

        private bool _hasInsCounter;

        private bool _hasPaintBooth;

        private bool _isHubStore;

        private bool _isOpenNightsWeekends;

        private int _newStoreNumber;

        private string _phoneNumber;

        private string _postalCode;

        private string _state;

        private IList _walls = new List();

        public virtual string Address1
        {
            get
            {
                return _address1;
            }
            set
            {
                _address1 = value;
            }
        }

        public virtual string Address2
        {
            get
            {
                return _address2;
            }
            set
            {
                _address2 = value;
            }
        }

        public virtual string City
        {
            get
            {
                return _city;
            }
            set
            {
                _city = value;
            }
        }

        public virtual string County
        {
            get
            {
                return _county;
            }
            set
            {
                _county = value;
            }
        }

        public virtual int OLDStoreNumber
        {
            get
            {
                return _oldStoreNumber;
            }
            set
            {
                _oldStoreNumber = value;
            }
        }

        public virtual string FaxNumber
        {
            get
            {
                return _faxNumber;
            }
            set
            {
                _faxNumber = value;
            }
        }

        public virtual bool HasHydraulicHose
        {
            get
            {
                return _hasHydraulicHose;
            }
            set
            {
                _hasHydraulicHose = value;
            }
        }

        public virtual bool HasInsCounter
        {
            get
            {
                return _hasInsCounter;
            }
            set
            {
                _hasInsCounter = value;
            }
        }

        public virtual bool HasPaintBooth
        {
            get
            {
                return _hasPaintBooth;
            }
            set
            {
                _hasPaintBooth = value;
            }
        }

        public virtual Guid Id
        {
            get
            {
                return _persistenceId;
            }
        }

        public virtual bool IsHubStore
        {
            get
            {
                return _isHubStore;
            }
            set
            {
                _isHubStore = value;
            }
        }

        public virtual bool IsOpenNightsWeekends
        {
            get
            {
                return _isOpenNightsWeekends;
            }
            set
            {
                _isOpenNightsWeekends = value;
            }
        }

        public virtual int NewStoreNumber
        {
            get
            {
                return _newStoreNumber;
            }
            set
            {
                _newStoreNumber = value;
            }
        }

        public virtual string PhoneNumber
        {
            get
            {
                return _phoneNumber;
            }
            set
            {
                _phoneNumber = value;
            }
        }
        public virtual string PostalCode
        {
            get
            {
                return _postalCode;
            }
            set
            {
                _postalCode = value;
            }
        }

        public virtual string State
        {
            get
            {
                return _state;
            }
            set
            {
                _state = value;
            }
        }

        public virtual IList Walls
        {
            get
            {
                return _walls.ToList().AsReadOnly();
            }
        }

        public virtual void AddWall(Wall wall)
        {
            wall.Store = this;
            _walls.Add(wall);
        }

    }
}
```

Get Action:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
        public ViewResult EditStore(Guid Id)
        {
            Store store;
            using (UnitOfWork.Start())
            {
                store = _storeRepository.GetStore(Id);
            }

            return View(store);
        }
```

Post Action (yes I realize there are no encoding checks etc, just rough here at first):

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
           public ActionResult EditStore(Store store)
        {
            using (UnitOfWork.Start())
            {
                _storeRepository.Update(store);

                UnitOfWork.Current.Flush();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("EditStore", store.Id);
        }
```

`<% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>`

```
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fields</legend>
        <p>
            <label for="Address1">Address1:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("Address1", Model.Address1) %>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Address1", "*") %>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="Address2">Address2:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("Address2", Model.Address2) %>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Address2", "*") %>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="City">City:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("City", Model.City) %>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("City", "*") %>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="County">County:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("County", Model.County) %>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("County", "*") %>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="OLDStoreNumber">OLDStoreNumber:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("OLDStoreNumber", Model.OLDStoreNumber) %>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("OLDStoreNumber", "*") %>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="FaxNumber">FaxNumber:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("FaxNumber", Model.FaxNumber) %>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("FaxNumber", "*") %>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="HasHydraulicHose">HasHydraulicHose:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("HasHydraulicHose", Model.HasHydraulicHose) %>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("HasHydraulicHose", "*") %>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="HasInsCounter">HasInsCounter:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("HasInsCounter", Model.HasInsCounter) %>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("HasInsCounter", "*") %>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="HasPaintBooth">HasPaintBooth:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("HasPaintBooth", Model.HasPaintBooth) %>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("HasPaintBooth", "*") %>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="IsHubStore">IsHubStore:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("IsHubStore", Model.IsHubStore) %>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("IsHubStore", "*") %>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="IsOpenNightsWeekends">IsOpenNightsWeekends:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("IsOpenNightsWeekends", Model.IsOpenNightsWeekends) %>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("IsOpenNightsWeekends", "*") %>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="NewStoreNumber">NewStoreNumber:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("NewStoreNumber", Model.NewStoreNumber) %>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("NewStoreNumber", "*") %>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="PhoneNumber">PhoneNumber:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("PhoneNumber", Model.PhoneNumber) %>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("PhoneNumber", "*") %>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="PostalCode">PostalCode:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("PostalCode", Model.PostalCode) %>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("PostalCode", "*") %>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="State">State:</label>
            <%= Html.TextBox("State", Model.State) %>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("State", "*") %>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>

<% } %>

<div>
    <%=Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") %>
</div>
```

Fiddler:

```
Address1=1234+Main+street&Address2=Suite+100&City=Anywhere&County=MyCounty&OLDStoreNumber=1&FaxNumber=18001112222&HasHydraulicHose=true&HasHydraulicHose=false&HasInsCounter=true&HasInsCounter=false&HasPaintBooth=false&IsHubStore=false&IsOpenNightsWeekends=false&NewStoreNumber=1&PhoneNumber=18001112222&PostalCode=11001&State=MyState
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the IoC framework I was using.  Well it wasn't a problem with the framework itself, but rather my configuration of it.  When using Castle Windsor for your IoC framework you must mark the containers being registered as having a lifestyle = Transient instead of the default Singleton.  If you allow the default it will wreak havoc when using it as I am.

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Rename the form elements to match the *objectname*.*propertyname*, like so:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("SomeNewObj.Id",Model.Id);
<%= Html.TextBox("SomeNewObj.Title",Model.Title);
```

where *SomeNewObj* is the name of the parameter to the POST method:

```
public ActionResult SomePostMethod(int id, Store SomeNewObj)
{
     //SomeNewObj.Title should be properly populated
     //...
}
```

ASP.NET MVC will make the association to the new Store object only if the form IDs include the name of the object parameter as well as its properties.

Remember to encode! :) I left that out in this example.

Comment: Gave that a shot, changing the first argument on TextBox to "store.Address1" and still no dice. Good idea though.

Answer (score 1):

Your form *must* include all non-nullable properties of the type, or the default model binder won't bind it. You say that you don't include the ID. Is this a non-nullable type like Guid or int? That's your problem.

There are two ways to work around this:

1. Change the type of the ID to a nullable type like Guid?
2. Add a "default" value for ID to the form, like Guid.Empty.

I note that you are using TextBoxes to bind to Boolean properties. This means that if any value is omitted or cannot be converted to Boolean, binding of the entire type will fail, because the properties are non-nullable. Using anything other than a checkbox to bind to a Boolean is a bit precarious. In general, if you design a type for model binding, you may want to make everything nullable in the case where a user not filling out one property doesn't mean that you don't want to see what they filled in for other properties.

Comment: I am guessing this is going to be the issue then.  It is a non=nullable Guid and only has a getter on the domain model.  Testing this theory, I will let you know what I find.

Comment: Gave this a try and still no dice.  Man this is driving me nuts.

Comment: Post the class definition and the form your page is submitting (from Firebug net tab or Fiddler).

Comment: You can add the class definition (and form contents) to your question by editing the question. I think the default binder is probably trying to bind but concluding that it doesn't have enough info in the form to materialize an instance of that type, but I can't figure out why without seeing the full form + class.

Comment: See updated answer. You didn't show the POSTed form, but I'll bet that one of the values for one of the Boolean properties cannot be converted to a Boolean by the model binder. Look very closely at the POSTed form in Fiddler or Firebug.

Comment: Bah, I knew I forgot something (edited). Even with CheckBox helpers it does not bind.  I do get things like HasHydraulicHose=true&HasHydraulicHose=false.  So your suggestion is to have a custom view model object with all nullable properties? Are there options for addressing the checkbox double value issue other than a custom view model?

Comment: For what it's worth, I always use presentation models. You don't have to use all nullable properties, but I think that nullable properties would help you in this case by making it clear which individual property the default model binder is not able to bind with the value the form is giving it. You could use a model with nullable properties for testing purposes only, even if you don't want to change the production application. The "double" value is a non-issue; that's how MVC checkboxes work. Search Stack Overflow for an explanation; it's been discussed here before.

Comment: Still stumped.  I tried a custom view model, tried Prefix="", tried using exclude on the id and the property that is an IList<T> colletion.  This is driving me nuts, I just don't get it.  I even commented out every single property but the Id and Address1 and it still wouldn't bind that simple object.

Comment: I don't see the Id in your form or your Store type. If it's in the type and non-nullable but not in the POSTed form, binding will fail.

Comment: Thank you very much for all of your help Craig.  I knew it was something in my set up.  Using Castle Windsor for the IoC framework I did not have the lifestlye type as Transient so it was defaulting to Singleton.  This was throwing a wrench in the works.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the UpdateModel(StoreObject);

Perhaps the values will get set.

Comment: That is the approach I have been attempting to use, but the StoreObject in your suggestion is not populated with the form data.  That is the problem I am having.  I can persist the information properly, I just am having trouble getting it from the form into the object parameter on the post method.

Answer (score 0):

I'd setup a CustomModelBinder for it.  for a little up front work, these payoff in the long run, believe me...

```
public class StoreModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override void OnModelUpdated(ControllerContext controllerContext,
                                           ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        Store store= 
            (Store)(bindingContext.Model ?? new Store());

        // For example...
        store.ID = Convert.ToInt32(controllerContext.HttpContext.Request["storeID"]);

        // Set other properties...
    }
}
```

You get reuse across controllers and actions AND your controllers don't have to worry about digesting FormCollections.

Comment: I am looking into this to see if it will address my needs. Does each model binder have to be registered separately in the app_start?

Comment: App start is the best place to register them.